# How to parse optional URL parameters

Tags: java, refactoring, url-parameters

I have a list of request parameters that all require different actions to be taken, but all of them are optional and any one of them could be null.  I'm brute-forcing it now with a series of if statements, but I'd like to clean it up with some sort of HashMap and a loop.  What would be the correct way to do this?

```
if(request.getParameter(VALUE_STRING) != null){
    complexObject.setValue(request.getParameter(VALUE_STRING));
}
if(request.getParameter(TYPE_STRING) != null){
    complexObject.setType(request.getParameter(TYPE_STRING));
}
if(request.getParameter(PATTERN_STRING) != null){
    complexObject.setPattern(Pattern.compile(request.getParameter(PATTERN_STRING)));
}
```

I can also add/modify functions on the complexObject class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a getParameterMap() method you can get from your request that gives you what you want, you could then switch on the values.  Here is a quick tutorial on said method: http://www.javatutorials.co.in/servlet-getparametermap-example/

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
    switch(entry.getKey()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

That being said, is there a reason you're accessing the request directly, and not using some variety of MVC?  This type of use case is quite trivial inside most MVC frameworks.

Comment: is there a way to do the inner function without a switch?

Comment: A giant else if like you have already.  A switch cuts down on gibberish, given the choice between the two.